# How can I group all these equations in just one group and write them without the error Missing $ inserted. ...gy}

Tags: equations, subequations

here is the equation I would like to write but it is not working as it should

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far

```
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:3.2}
     & \[(EQE)= \frac{photons_{out}}{electrons_{in}}\]

     & = \frac{radiant flux / photon energy}{injected current / elementary charge}
        \end{equation}
```

Comment: Please show a compilable minimal working example (MWE) showing what you have tried so far

Comment: Nest an  `amsmath` `aligned` environment in an `equation`.

Comment: You are putting math mode (`\[\]`) inside math mode (`equation`). Remove `\[` and `\]`.  Also, use `\text` for `photon`, `out`, `radiant flux`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nesting math mode `\[ \]` in another math environment `{equation}`. This is a recommended version of your equation.

Some notes:

- The number should go to the last line of the equation.
- Use `\text` from `amsmath` to display text.
- Use `align` from `amsmath` to align equations on different lines.
- Don't use numbers in labels. Use meaningful labels for `\label`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \text{EQE}&=\frac{\#\,\text{photons}_{\text{out}}}{\#\,\text{electrons}_\text{in}}\nonumber\\
  &=\frac{\text{radiation flux}/\text{photon energy}}{\text{injected current}/\text{elementary charge}}\nonumber\\
  &=\frac{\Phi_e/E_{\text{ph}}}{I_{\text{in}/e}}=\frac{\Phi_e\times e}{I_{\text{in}\times E_{\text{ph}}}}\nonumber\\
  &=\frac{\pi\times A\times L_{\text{v}}\times e\times \lambda_{\text{average}}}{K_{\text{m}}\times V(\lambda_{\text{peak}})\times I_{\text{in}}\times hc}\label{eq:somename}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for "Use meaningful labels for `\label`."

Comment: If there's any chance such an expression might appear in a theorem or other italic environment, you want to use either `\mathrm` or `\textup` to ensure that the "words" don't become italic.  `\text` follows the upright or italic style of the surrounding text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would say that in an italic environment, I want those text to be italic as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a single `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment. I would also use `\mathrm` and `\textnormal` for words and acronyms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % optional

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4}  % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{4}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:EQE}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{EQE}
&= \frac{\textnormal{\#photons}_{\textnormal{out}}}{\textnormal{\#electrons}_{\textnormal{in}}}\\
&= \frac{\textnormal{radiant flux}/\textnormal{photon energy}}{\textnormal{injected current}/\textnormal{elementary charge}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```